# Did Android Gmail 4.2.1 break html intents?

Tags: android, html, android-intent, gmail

I've been using Intents to send HTML formatted emails using Gmail on Android from other apps. Today they stopped working. They look good in the Gmail compose display but all of the HTML tags get stripped when Gmail sends the email.

I've tried every variation of Intent formatting that I've seen posted and all HTML is stripped away. The result is always a multipart/alternative with a plain text and an HTML section containing an HTML-ized version of the plain text.

Is anyone else seeing this?

Any ideas for a work-around?

Comment: You might consider actually posting the code in question. It is difficult for us to advise you regarding your code without seeing your code.

Comment: I think this is actually an important question.  It is a major regression in functionality of the GMail app.  I have opened a similar question with more details in the hopes that we might get some kind of resolution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13756200/send-html-email-with-gmail-4-2-1