# losing hyperlinks in the email android

Tags: android, android-intent, html-email

i have tried this

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
mIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "this is test");
mIntent.setType("text/html");  
Uri myUri = Uri.parse("http://www.Google.com/");
mIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,Html.fromHtml("<a href=\""+myUri+"\">Link</a>"));
            context.startActivity(android.content.Intent.createChooser(mIntent, "Email:"));
```

and i have also tried with 
 setType("message/rfc822");

all in vain, i don't have problem with the email (that works fine). but i am unable to see the hyperlink, the original message when received on the other end doesn't even have the hyper link href the content shown below

```
*MIME-Version: 1.0
Received: by 10.49.25.98 with HTTP; Thu, 3 Jan 2013 08:42:55 -0800 (PST)
Received: by 10.49.25.98 with HTTP; Thu, 3 Jan 2013 08:42:55 -0800 (PST)
Date: Thu, 3 Jan 2013 11:42:55 -0500
Delivered-To: DELETED
Message-ID: DELETED
Subject: this is test
From: DELETED
To: DELETED
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=047d7bea41ce0280df04d2650e27
--047d7bea41ce0280df04d2650e27
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
Link
--047d7bea41ce0280df04d2650e27
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
<p dir="ltr">Link</p>
--047d7bea41ce0280df04d2650e27--*
```

Comment: There is no requirement of a mail client to support HTML mail, or to leave it untouched, if you are using `ACTION_SEND`. In particular, you are going to be limited by the editing environment of the message composer of the email client. If the editor does not support HTML, your HTML will probably be de-tagged as part of sending the email.

Comment: read Html.fromHtml documentation (and return type) before using it. and ask yourself, what do you expect it to do, exactly ?

Comment: perhaps you are a victim of what appears to be a pretty ugly regression in GMail 4.2.1?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13756200/send-html-email-with-gmail-4-2-1

Comment: this is true but is there a way to send a hyper link with in the email via intent or is it like dont send hyperlinks?

Comment: in versions of the GMail app prior to 4.2.1 you could add hyperlinks in just the manner that you are showing here and they would work as expected.

Comment: ok so as a remedy and to avoid Gmail app adding a bad behavior to my app , im removing hyperlinks, at least user can click on the link if it is in text, Thanks all,

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, recipients);
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,Html.fromHtml(emailtext.toString()));
emailIntent.setType("text/html");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
```

Works well with the emailtext set as:

```
String emailtext = "<a href="+actionUrl+">"+shareTextContent+"</a>";
```

action url may be something like :

```
actionUrl = "www.google.com"
```