# Send HTML email with Gmail 6.11.6 using intent

Tags: android, html, email, android-intent, gmail

I've been using intents to send HTML formatted emails using Gmail on Android from my app. It was working fine but now it does not show formatting even in Gmail compose display. Is there another bug in the Gmail app again or what??

**Note:** I have gone through these questions already
[bug in gmail 4.something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13756200/send-html-email-with-gmail-4-2-1)
and
[broken gmail intents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13712454/did-android-gmail-4-2-1-break-html-intents)

My code looks like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType(HTML_TEXT);
String htmlContentInStringFormat = createHtmlforEmail(context, name, channelLink);
if (htmlContentInStringFormat != null) {
   intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(htmlContentInStringFormat));
   }
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, name);
```

**Note 2:** It was working fine previously so there is nothing wrong with the HTML.

My HTML looks like this

```
<div align="center">
<font size="5" color="#D0021B" face="Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif">CHARE</font>
<p><font size="3" color="black" face="Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif">Dear Receiver,</font></p><p><font size="3" color="black" face="Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif">The sender of this email wants to invite you to this CHARE channel %1$s. Please click the subscribe button below to subscribe the channel.</font> </p> <p><a href=%2$s><font size="5" color="#5188de" face="Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif">Subscribe</font></a> </p> <p><font size="3" color="black" face="Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif">More information is available under</font></br><a href="www.chare.one"><font size="3" color="#5188de" face="Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif">www.chare.one</font></a></p></div>
```

I have also tried very simple version of HTML which is given below

```
"Hello, here is some <b>bold text</b> some <u>underline text</u> and <a href=\"http://www.google.com\">a link</a>."
```

But Gmail still does not set the formatting.
It will be great if someone points me to right direction.

Suggestions related to some alternatives will be welcomed.

Comment: Did you find a fix for this? I have the same problem using any of the common "send html email via intent" solutions, including your code, on Gmail v6.11.2 and 7.1.129.

Comment: I think Gmail have removed this functionality.

Comment: Have you check if you are viewing the email as HTML, and not as Plain Text on Gmail?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it can help you, I made it in a java web application just a week ago. Here is my method:

```
private JavaMailSender mailSender;

public void sendEmail(final userDTO dto, String pathFile) {
    MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
    MimeMessageHelper helper;
    try {
        helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message);
        helper.setTo(dto.getEmail());
        helper.setFrom(the_email_you_want_to_show);
        helper.setText(loadTemplate(pathFile), true);
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try{
        mailSender.send(message);
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and then I use this method to load the template:

```
public String loadTemplate(String pathFile){
    Document doc = null;
    DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    domFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = null;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        docBuilder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        doc = docBuilder.parse(EmailSender.class.getResourceAsStream(pathFile), "UTF-8");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try(StringWriter sw = new StringWriter()){
        Source xmlSource = new DOMSource(doc);
        TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer().transform(xmlSource, new StreamResult(sw));
        sb.append(sw.toString());
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return sb.toString().trim();
}
```

remember to configure your smtp configuration. in my app I used spring where I use a bean but you should populate the JavaMailSender with these properties

```
   org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl
    host="smtp.gmail.com"
    port="587"
    username="yourGmail@gmail.com"
    password="yourPassword"
    javaMailProperties
       props
          prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
          prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
          prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
       props
```

I'm sorry if this last part is not clear but it's a spring bean configuration. you should set these properties in java manually(mailSender.set...).
I assume you configured the settings in you gmail account, because without the proper settings it won't work, but I think you're ok if you say you already sent some mails. If you find some useless code it's beacuse I quickly modified my original code.

Comment: thanks for your reply but the question is strictly related to Android and iteration with the Gmail App.